# Recreate Photoshop's "mixer brush tool" for painting iOS app

Tags: ios, xcode, photoshop

I'm attempting to create a painting app for iOS. One feature I hope to have is like Photoshop's "Mixer Brush Tool." In Photoshop you can adjust the wetness, mix and flow of the brush.

I looked at all the core image effects, even the distortion effects but did not see anything similar. Anyone know of any sample code that does this? If not, any direction to guide me through would be great. I'm stuck at the moment.

[image]

Comment: This question is not really appropriate for Stack Overflow, but... GNU Image Manipulation Program (GIMP) has a "Smudge" tool like that. It's open-source, so you could dig into it if you want to look for a "direction."

Comment: Thank you okay going to look at that. If anyone else has ideas or directions please please send.

Comment: If you want to try digging into things with Core Image, I expect this type of effect is a very localized application of [Motion Blur](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIMotionBlur). Of course, it won't be as simple as just applying a filter... but that's why companies write - and (usually) sell - image editing software :)

Comment: Thank you @DonMag yes I was looking at the Core Image Effects and didn't see anything like smudge. The twirl distortion was the only thing that felt like smudge but it's twirl... Still looking....